# I am getting undefined from express. Why req.body is showing empty object {}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

This is noob question but I am new to it. Req.body is undefined. I tried without body-

parser and with body-parser, I keep getting the same result I tried all solutions

available in StackOverflow but I keep getting the same result.

This is my client side code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                var message = { name: document.getElementById('name').value, message: document.getElementById('message').value }
                postMessages(message)
            })
            getMessages()

        });
        function addMessages(message) {
            const ele = document.getElementById('messages')
            const h4 = document.createElement('h4')
            const p = document.createElement('p')
            h4.textContent = `${message.name}`
            p.textContent = `${message.message}`
            ele.append(h4, p)
        }
        function postMessages(message) {
            const Url = "http://localhost:3000/messages"
            fetch(Url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: message,
            })
        }
```

And this is my NodeJs code:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
var messages = [
    { name: "Tim", message: "Hi" },
    { name: "Jane", message: "Hello" }
]
app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    messages.push(req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Comment: What is the actual request body you can see in the browser dev tools? Could you post a [mcve] of the client?

Comment: VM150:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'O', "OK" is not valid JSON

Comment: Why does the client send an error message to the server?

Comment: I am new to it. Don't know the reason.

Comment: Can you try `fetch(Url, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringiffy(message), })`?

Comment: Still same error. I am sharing full code

Comment: No, don't share full code. Create a [mcve].

Comment: Keep `JSON.stringify` and add this to your fetch `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: Now I am getting correct result. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your fetch function and first `JSON.stringify` your message and then add correct headers:

```
function postMessages(message) {
        const Url = "http://localhost:3000/messages"
        fetch(Url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(message),
        })
    }
```